# Embedded Jetty - Spring MVC - view resolver - NO XML - HTTP ERROR: 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to set up a simple Spring MVC server using embedded Jetty. I've set up the server, enabled spring and configured a view resolver for .jsp files. The controller gives me 404 with the following message:

```
Problem accessing /jsp/test.jsp. Reason:
Not Found
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? I've been googling for two days.

The server:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;
private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/";
private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "spring.config";
private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/*";

private EmbeddedJettyServer(){
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(DEFAULT_PORT);
    server.setHandler(getServletContextHandler(getContext()));
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

private static ServletContextHandler getServletContextHandler(WebApplicationContext context) throws IOException {
    ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    contextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
    contextHandler.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
    contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(context)), MAPPING_URL);
    contextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    contextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
    return contextHandler;
}

private static WebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
    return context;
}
```

Spring config / View resolver:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="controller")
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/html/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/html/");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("test");
}
```

Edit:
Folder structure:

```
│   pom.xml
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   ├───controller
│   │   │   │       Ping.java
│   │   │   │       Prime.java
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───run
│   │   │   │       EmbeddedJettyServer.java
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───spring
│   │   │       └───config
│   │   │               WebMvcConfig.java
│   │   │
│   │   ├───resources
│   │   │   ├───html
│   │   │   │       test.html
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───jsp
│   │   │           test.jsp
│   │   │
│   │   └───webapp
│   │       └───jsp
│   │               test.jsp
│   │
│   └───test
│       └───java
└───target
```

Pom.xml:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>/webapp</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Does jsp/test.jsp exist in your project?

Comment: Yes. Will add folder structure to original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
In "EmbeddedJettyServer" I changed

```
"MAPPING_URL" to "/".
"ServletContextHandler" to "WebAppContext"
```

Added missin dependency in pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.0.M0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also had to configure IDE to use JDK instead of JRE

Comment: Which servlet version you used ? I get exception`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I`