# Error 404: Issue accessing /WEB-INF/views/sendMessage.jsp. Reason: Not Found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jetty

I have been struggling with this for hours. I cannot get my simple Jetty + Spring MVC + JSP web application to work.

Here is the directory structure of my project:

```
spring-form-utf-8-test
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
|   `-- main
|       |-- java
|       |   |-- com
|       |   |   `-- example
|       |   |       |-- beans
|       |   |       |   `-- forms
|       |   |       |       `-- MessageForm.java
|       |   |       |-- config
|       |   |       |   `-- WebMvcConfig.java
|       |   |       `-- controller
|       |   |           `-- FormController.java
|       |   `-- Main.java
|       |-- resources
|       `-- webapp
|           |-- images
|           |   `-- kitty.jpg
|           `-- WEB-INF
|               `-- views
|                   `-- sendMessage.jsp
`-- target
```

The problem is that when I am trying to access `http://localhost:8080` I am getting the following error.

[image: Error 404]

I run the server from the command line:

```
java -jar target\spring-form-utf-8-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The controller looks like this and I do not see anything wrong with the mapping:

```
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.beans.forms.MessageForm;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FormController {

    @ModelAttribute("message")
    public MessageForm createMessageForm() {
        return new MessageForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sendForm() {
        return "sendMessage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("message") @Valid final MessageForm message,
        final BindingResult result,
        final Model model) {
        return "sendMessage";
    }
}
```

The annotated web application context looks like this

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.controller")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("images/**").addResourceLocations("images/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

And the main class which runs the Jetty server instance looks like this.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Server server = new Server(8080);
        final ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");

        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.example.config");
        context.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("dev");

        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(context)), "/*");
        servletContextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));


        try {
        servletContextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        server.setHandler(servletContextHandler);
        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Accessing a static resource `http://localhost:8080/images/kitty.jpg` works without any problem. Also if I change the controller to not be mapped to a view but instead `@ResponseBody` annotation is used, then I can see the result in the browser.

I have tried to add a `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` instance like it is presented on [this blog](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.de/2013/05/embedding-jetty9-spring-mvc.html) but this did not bring any results. The error message is the same.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460060/embedded-jetty-spring-mvc-view-resolver-no-xml-http-error-404) stackoverflow post.

In my case changing the `import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler` to `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext` worked like a charm.

In the end the `Main.java` file looks as follows.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Server server = new Server(8080);
        final WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setErrorHandler(null);
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/");

        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.example.config");
        context.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("dev");

        webAppContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(context)), "/");
        webAppContext.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));


        try {
            webAppContext.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        server.setHandler(webAppContext);
        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

It was also essential to change `/*` to `/` in this line of code:

```
webAppContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(context)), "/");
```